# knockout push values array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

when I click on button1 I get object with 50 contacts array **(containing collection of arrays with phoneNumbers, Addresses...)**, then when I click on button 2 I get the same object but my first object is erased whereas I would like to display 50 + 50 = 100 contacts array. I tried concat method but I have some difficulties to implement.

```
   viewModel.initializeListener = function() {

    $('#button1').click(function() {
        document.getElementById("button2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        $('#retrievedContactsDiv').html('');
         nbDisplayedContacts = 0;
        console.info("test");
         viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.MoreContacts();



    });

    $('#button2').click(function() {
        viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.MoreContacts();
        console.info("test");
    });

    }; `


  viewModel.WeHaveMoreContacts = function(data) {
    console.info("test:", data)
    if (viewModel.MoreContacts) {

        var newArray=ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel.MoreContacts);
           var concatenated = newArray.concat(dataArray);
           viewModel.MoreContacts.contacts(concatenated);


    } else {
        viewModel.MoreContacts = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        var dataArray = viewModel.MoreContacts.contacts();

    }
```

I have a parameter with number of contacts to skip for the server.

function which call the server then call the mapping function :

```
viewModel.ui.FlashbackReport.MoreContacts()
```

Problem :  Object # has no method 'concat'

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle showing a complete example of what  you want to do? It is not clear with the code you posted.

Comment: my code is too long with jsonp requests, thx for help anyway

Answer (score 1):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reRRV/) that may help you.

The first part of the function generates new contacts and the second one add them to the existing contacts.

```
var VM = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray();

    self.addMore = function () {
        // simulate server response 
        var offset = self.contacts().length;
        var dataFromServer = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            dataFromServer.push({
                name: 'contact ' + offset + index
            });
        }
        // add each new item to existing items.
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(dataFromServer, function (item) {
            self.contacts.push(item);
        });

    };
}
```

Feel free to ask more explanation.

I hope it helps.